# Lambda is not waiting for Async/Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Lamda ends the process and it's not waiting for the API response. here is my code:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, cb) => {

 try {
    console.log('FETCHING RECORDS FROM DATOCMS')
    const allItems = await client.items.all({}, { allPages: true })
    if (!fs.existsSync(backupDir)){
        // Create backup directory
        console.log('CRETING BACKUP DIRECTORY')
        fs.mkdirSync(backupDir, { recursive: true });
    }

    console.log('FILL JSON WITH RECORDS FETCHED FROM DATOCMS')
    fs.writeFileSync('backup/records.json', JSON.stringify(allItems, null, 2));

    console.log('ADDING BACKUP FOLDER TO ZIP')
    zip.addLocalFolder(backupDir);
    const zipFileContents = zip.toBuffer();
    
    const params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        Key: `backup_zip-${backupDate}`,
        Body: zipFileContents,
        ContentType: "application/zip",
        ContentDisposition: `attachment; filename="${fileName}-${backupDate}"`
    }

    console.log('UPLOADING ZIP TO S3', params)
    s3.putObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            cb(null, 'Error')
            throw new Error('The zip file could not be uploaded', err);
        }
        console.log('Uploaded correctly')
        cb(null, 'Success')
        fs.rmdirSync(backupDir, { recursive: true });
    })
 } catch (err) {
    cb(null, 'Error..')
    throw new Error('An error occurred', err)
 }
}
```

I also tried adding this two lines with no luck

```
 setInterval(() => {}, 1000);
 context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

Can anyone help me?
I've been testing Promises, Async/Await, Callbacks and no luck with that. Thanks!

[This is the response in CloudWatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Fra.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to map the promises, then `await` on `Promise.all`. I'm not sure if `all` returns array of promises.

```
const promises =  client.items.map(it=>...)
const promises =  client.items.all(it=>...)
await Promise.all(promises)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't waiting for `s3.putObject`. It should be:

```
const data = s3.putObject(params).promise();
```

You handle the error in a try/catch.

Comment: I did that, but the problem is with the await call, I need that data to be wrapped into a zip and then uploaded to S3

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `async` keyword from the handler. You can't use the callback function in the async/await function.

Try to use the aws sdk function with `.promise();`

Comment: I did that, but the problem is with the await call

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to understand, you either use callback-style (`handler = (event, context, callback) => {})`) or promise-style (`handler = async (event, context)`). Do not combine both.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        console.log('FETCHING RECORDS FROM DATOCMS');
        const allItems = await client.items.all({}, {allPages: true});
        if (!fs.existsSync(backupDir)) {
            // Create backup directory
            console.log('CRETING BACKUP DIRECTORY');
            fs.mkdirSync(backupDir, {recursive: true});
        }

        console.log('FILL JSON WITH RECORDS FETCHED FROM DATOCMS');
        fs.writeFileSync('backup/records.json', JSON.stringify(allItems, null, 2));

        console.log('ADDING BACKUP FOLDER TO ZIP');
        zip.addLocalFolder(backupDir);
        const zipFileContents = zip.toBuffer();

        const params = {
            Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
            Key: `backup_zip-${backupDate}`,
            Body: zipFileContents,
            ContentType: 'application/zip',
            ContentDisposition: `attachment; filename="${fileName}-${backupDate}"`
        };

        console.log('UPLOADING ZIP TO S3', params);
        // We switch this to use a promise.
        await s3.putObject(params).promise();
        fs.rmdirSync(backupDir, {recursive: true});
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error('An error occurred', err);
    }
};
```